# Looking for a tool that will place the cursor to a specific x,y coordinate

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I am a new user to Quantum GIS. I am looking for a tool/function that will allow a user to type in coordinates, and place the cursor on that exact position. This is for navigation in the field...

Here is a bit of context...

I need to provide a laptop with an interactive map to a colleague. He will hike around with a gps and the laptop. When he stops, he will check his position on the gps, and (hopefully) be able to type in the coords in QGIS on the laptop to see were he is on the map.

I know how to do this with ArcGIS (its the "go to x,y" tool).

Hopefully there is something similar in QGIS.

Thanks a million!

Answer (score 16):

For QGIS 3.x and 2.x there is a plugin called **Lat Lon Tools**
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/latlontools/

It will let you enter coordinates in a variety of formats and pan to them at the current zoom level.  It also has a variety of other features.

[image: Coordinate entry interface]

The location is marked with a red crosshairs

[image: Crosshair on map]

Comment: You have linked to the wrong plugin (ZoomToCoordinates, which does not work in 3.x) The URL for Lat Lon Tools is https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/latlontools/

Answer (score 11):

You can do just pasting/typing X,Y value in status bar and hit enter and change scale to zoom in/out. See image below

[image]

Comment: Is this true?  Does not seem to work for me.  After pasting coordinates and hitting enter, nothing.

Comment: It works for me

Comment: that works for me, but it doesn't mark the location, just give you an extent

Answer (score 10):

- From Plugins Menu -> Featch Python Plugins.
- Install ZoomToCoordinates Plugin.
- On entering the x and y, it will flash a cursor on the location.

[image]